# Invalid Hook Call while trying to use Material UI

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to add search icon from material UI but I am getting this error. "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." I was trying the amazon clone tutorial from YouTube and did everything exactly. Can someone help me? Thank you.

This is my Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

function Header() {
  return (
    <nav className="header">
      {/* Logo on the left -> img */}
      <Link to="/">
        <img className="header__logo" src="/logo.png"></img>
      </Link>

      {/* Search box */}

      <input type="text" className="header__serachInput"/>
    <SearchIcon />


      {/* Links */}
      {/* Basket icon with number */}
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "amazon-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty fine and I don't see the use of hooks in your code here.

Try updating your react-dom module.
[See the update error here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13972#issuecomment-433178133)